# Docker fails with Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: java, docker, debian

Im having issues trying to install JRE into my docker container.

I keep getting the error message;

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.38.1+dfsg-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-11-jre:amd64
 default-jre
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I scroll up the build output a bit, I also see the following issues;

```
Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.11-71) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.4+11-1~deb10u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link '/usr/share/man/man1/rmid.1.gz.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 installed openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-11-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-11-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11.0.4+11-1~deb10u1); however:
  Package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre:
 default-jre depends on openjdk-11-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-11-jre:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20190405) ...
head: cannot open '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts' for reading: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile is very simple, but it just wont work

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    wget \
    default-jre \
    nginx
```

It looks to be using `debian buster`, any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying for days.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`jre` installation require `man` folder to exist on the server, try this:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    wget \
    default-jre \
    nginx
```

Comment: Why are you installing nginx through apt while using the nginx image?

Comment: I am not, but the OP does, I only point out how to solve the Problem maybe he has his resons ....

Comment: @LinPy ... I seem to be getting another error `WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.install4j.runtime.util.ToolTipHelpLabel` ... Would you happen to know anything about this one?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some background on this issue. This happens because the post install script tries to run `update-alternatives` for java and the folder `/usr/share/man/man1` is not present as was already explained in the LinPy`s answer.

The following Debian bug discusses this problem in more details and also documents the workaround by creating them issing folder:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=863199#23

It seems this issue was recently closed for OpenJDK 8 but it seems to be still open in the newer JDKs, see:

https://salsa.debian.org/openjdk-team/openjdk/-/blob/master/debian/JB-jdk-headless.postinst.in

The following patch can fix this and should probably be added also to newer OpenJDK versions:

```
diff --git a/debian/JB-jdk-headless.postinst.in b/debian/JB-jdk-headless.postinst.in
index 0e1ef5f..e3afef1 100644
--- a/debian/JB-jdk-headless.postinst.in
+++ b/debian/JB-jdk-headless.postinst.in
@@ -43,6 +43,7 @@ configure)
     if [ -n "$multiarch" ] && [ "$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_ARCH" != $(dpkg --print-architecture) ]; then
        priority=$(expr $priority - 1)
     fi
+    test -d /usr/share/man/man1 || mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
     for i in $jdk_hl_tools; do
        unset slave1 slave2 || true
         if [ -e $mandir/man1/$i.$srcext ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because some of your packages were not configured properly during installation or multiple background processes were using the same file. E.g. if two processes simultaneously use the same file, the system locks the file, which is causing errors. You can fix this by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

- `sudo` means to run the command with super user privileges
- `dpkg` is a package manager for Debian-based Linux distribution
- `--configure` is used to configure unpacked programs or packages
- `-a` means that all unpacked (but unconfigured) packages will be configured

Reference: [here](https://linuxhint.com/dpkg-configure/)